# wso2 ei 6.5 SOAP Client and REST Service The parameter received is XML Rest need to json

Tags: wso2-esb

```
  <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="ctc"
           startOnLoad="true"
           statistics="enable"
           trace="disable"
           transports="http,https">
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <log>
                <property name="******" value="---ctc---"/>
             </log>
             <property xmlns:saop="http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/EsbJyBpel/src/saopWSDL"
                       expression="$body//saop:upload/xml"
                       name="request_msg"/>
    
             <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="request_msg"/>
             </log>
             <property name="messageType"     
                       scope="axis2"
                       type="STRING"
                       value="application/json"/>
             <script language="js">mc.setPayloadJSON(
                            {
                                    "Code" : "10",
                                    "Price" : "11"
                     });</script>
             <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" value="POST"/>
                      <property name="messageType"
                       scope="axis2"
                       type="STRING"
                       value="application/json"/>
                        <property name="Content-Type"
                          value="application/json"
                          scope="transport"
                          type="STRING"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address format="pox" uri="http://192.16.110.142:8081/dqcsweb/ES/test"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send> 
    
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="res_msg"/>
             </log>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
    
    </proxy>
```

---

The XML structure that the restful service log prints;
How do You convert an XML structure to JSON?

I used script and payloadFactory, output the JSON string in the ESB, and the print log in the invoked service is still XML

input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdwTt.png)

The message received by the service(http://192.16.110.142:8081/dqcsweb/ES/test):

```
 <jsonObject><Code>10</Code><Price>11</Price></jsonObject>
```

expectations:

```
{
   "code":"10",
   "Price":"11"
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this. Do you want to log a JSON value or do you want to send a JSON value to the backend? Please add the output received and also the expected output to help you with this issue

Comment: I have reedited it,Please take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the format of the endpoint invoked to rest. Please refer to the follwoing sample configuration.

```
        <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="rest" uri="http://192.16.110.142:8081/dqcsweb/ES/test"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
```

The used pox format results in the message transformed into plain old XML format. Please refer to the documentation [1] to further clarify this.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Address+Endpoint

**Update**
Can you enable wire logs by uncommenting the following [2] in log4j.properties file. You need to perform a server restart to enable this. This allows you to see the request sent out of the EI server. Please check if the request going out of the EI contains the necessary payload.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Debugging+Mediation#DebuggingMediation-Viewingwirelogs

Comment: The service receives an empty string

Comment: Required request body is missing

Comment: The pure version can be tuned through,I don't know what the formal environment is configured for

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the above statement

Comment: I can request to the service and send the correct JSON, but WSO2 EI 6.5 in the formal environment cannot pass the request